# Executing vb.net Code Behind Method after Plupload finish uploading

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net, plupload

Stumbled into another roadblock. Right now I have a page containing `Plupload` and a repeater that basically pulls all the uploaded images from database. This page is loaded dynamically in `colorbox`.

What I need is for the repeater to update itself when new images is uploaded into the database. I do this by just calling the Repeater and databind it (Repeater1.Databind()). I'm pretty sure the solution lies in `Ajax` but I've looked around and have even used them to call a web service but how do you execute a code behind method?

The code behind method that I want to execute is:

```
Public Sub reBind()
    Dim dt2 As DataTable = blOrgLogo.getOrgLogo(userId, False).Tables(0)
    If (dt2 Is Nothing) Or (dt2.Rows.Count = 0) Then
        ' Nothing is returned
    Else
        repLogoCollection.DataSource = dt2
        repLogoCollection.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

One example I saw online state that this can be done use `PageMethods` but I can't get it to work with the above mentioned method.

I can't use the `ASP.Net Ajax Timer` control as it just doesn't seem to be working when the page is loaded through colorbox. (If anyone have a solution for this it would be awesome as that would simplify everything haha)

Another piece of info that I'm not sure may be of any use is that the repeater is binded in page_load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    userId = Session("UserID")
    Dim dt As DataTable = blOrgLogo.getOrgLogo(userId, False).Tables(0)

    If (Not IsPostBack) Then
        If (dt Is Nothing) Or (dt.Rows.Count = 0) Then
            ' Nothing is returned
        Else
            Repeater1.DataSource = dt
            Repeater1.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The Plupload javascript:

```
// Client side form validation
$('#uploader').submit(function (e) {
    var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

    // Validate number of uploaded files
    if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
        // Files in queue upload them first
        if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function () {
                if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
                    $('form').submit();
            });

            uploader.start();


        } else
            alert('You must at least upload one file.');

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you reload the page after upload? It seems quite complicated what you doing for simple task,

Comment: The page is in a colorbox which is why I wanted to do it this way. But most likely I'm gonna ditch the colorbox

Comment: OK well is it not an iframe or something in the colorbox? if so relaod the iframe.. if its ajaxed html.. then re ajax it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
//Location to the webservice or the webmethod
            url: "Services/Service.asmx/reBind",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            //on success     
            },
            error: function(ex) {
           //on error            
            }
        });
```

And above your method add `[WebMethod(true)]` you may need to find the vb.net equivalant of this as that is what i used for c#.

As for the ajax call im not sure if you have to have the code in a web service I am pretty sure even if it is in a class it will work, you may have to try both.